# How to reset a v-input-file with vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to reset my v-input-file when i click on a button. But, i don't see any function to do that.
I tried the following commands :
(upload_json is the name of my v-input-file)

```
this.$refs.upload_json.files=[]
this.$refs.upload_json.files=null
this.$refs.upload_json.value=""
this.$refs.upload_json.reset()
```

For all the commands, I had the same following error :

Uncaught TypeError: proxy set handler returned false for property

Comment: Could you share us some more of your code?
Perhaps make a codepen, you can use this link by vuetify: https://template.vuetifyjs.com

Answer (score 1):

You can clear input by using this approach

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-file-input
        v-model="files"
        accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/bmp"
        placeholder="Pick an avatar"
        prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
        label="Avatar"
    ></v-file-input>
   <v-btn @click="restInput">Clear Input</v-btn>
 </v-app>
</div>
```

main.js

```
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    files:{},
  }),
  methods:{
    restInput(){
      this.files = {}
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `this.$refs.upload_json.value=null`

Comment: Same error : TypeError: proxy set handler returned false for property

Answer (score 0):

You can clear input this way:

```
this.$refs.upload_json.internalValue = this.multiple ? [] : null
```

I tested it and it works. If you look at the [source of the v-file component](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VFileInput/VFileInput.ts#L165), that is how Vuetify developers clear the `input` when you click on the `clear` icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

`this.$refs.upload_json.$refs.input.value = null`

With Vue2, there was no warning as well!